# Uploading a file using "fetch" in reactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, fetch, multer

Uploading a file using "fetch" in reactjs

I am trying to upload a file using ReactJS.

```
handleUploadfile = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('photo',event.target.files[0] );
        data.append('name', 'Test Name');
        data.append('desc', 'Test description');
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/todo/upload", {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
             },
             body: data
        }).then((response) =>  {
           return response.text();
        })
    }
```

For some reason I am not able read the files at nodejs(+multer) server using:

`req.files`

which shows "undefined" at post router.

Comment: Use `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found the solution

I had to remove the 'Content-Type' from headers section and it worked out in nodejs using multer.

Using the "multipart/form-data"

`'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`

requires us to set boundaries and hence it is throwing error at nodejs "Error: Multipart: Boundary not found"

Using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

`'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

I am getting the req.body filled but as string but not able to access the individual values.

Hence final solution is removal of 'Content-Type'

Comment: Removing 'Content-Type' from header worked for me

Comment: when i remove the header, chrome sends it as plain text and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm uploading excel file and passing it to fetch method and working as I expected way

```
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('file', payload)

            const createXHR = () => new XMLHttpRequest()

            fetch('https://localhost:8080/file/', {
                body: formData,
                createXHR,
                method: 'POST'
            }).then(response => {
                return response.json()
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res, 'res')
            })
```